Replicate a LSTM Cell
Consider the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows,calc, shapes,positioning,shadows,arrows.meta,calligraphy,ext.paths.ortho}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{LSTM Cell.}
    \fbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\scriptsize,
    >=LaTeX,
    cell/.style={% For the main box
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners=5mm, 
    draw,
    very thick,
    },
    operator/.style={%For operators like +  and  x
    circle,
    draw,
    inner sep=-0.5pt,
    minimum width =.3cm,
    minimum height =.3cm,
    },
    function/.style={%For functions
    ellipse,
    draw,
    inner sep=1pt
    },
    ct/.style={% For external inputs and outputs
    circle,
    draw,
    line width = .75pt,
    minimum width=1cm,
    inner sep=1pt,
    },
    gt1/.style={% For internal inputs
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=green, 
    minimum width=4mm,
    minimum height=3mm,
    inner sep=1pt
    },
    gt2/.style={% For internal inputs
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=red, 
    minimum width=4mm,
    minimum height=3mm,
    inner sep=1pt
    },
    gt3/.style={% For internal inputs
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=yellow, 
    minimum width=4mm,
    minimum height=3mm,
    inner sep=1pt
    },
    ArrowC1/.style={% Arrows with rounded corners
    rounded corners=.25cm,
    thick,
    },
    ArrowC2/.style={% Arrows with big rounded corners
    rounded corners=.5cm,
    thick,
    },
    ]
    
    %Start drawing the thing\dots    
    % Draw the cell: 
    \node [cell, minimum height =4cm, minimum width=6cm] at (0,0){} ;
    
    % Draw inputs named ibox#
    \node [gt1] (ibox1) at (-2,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
    \node [gt2] (ibox2) at (-1.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
    \node [gt2, minimum width=1cm] (ibox3) at (-0.5,-0.75) {Tanh};
    \node [gt3] (ibox4) at (0.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
    
    % Draw opérators   named mux# , add# and func#
    \node [operator] (mux1) at (-2,1.5) {$\times$};
    \node [operator] (add1) at (-0.5,1.5) {+};
    \node [operator] (mux2) at (-0.5,0) {$\times$};
    \node [gt3] (mux3) at (1.5,0) {$\times$};
    \node [gt3] (func1) at (1.5,0.75) {Tanh};
    
    % Draw External inputs? named as basis c,h,x
    \node[] (c) at (-4,1.5) {$C_{t-1}$};
    \node[] (h) at (-4,-1.5) {$y_{t-1}$};
    \node[] (x) at (-2.5,-3) {$x_{t}$};
    
    % Draw External outputs? named as basis c2,h2,x2
    \node[] (c2) at (4,1.5) {$C_{t}$};
    \node[] (h2) at (4,-1.5) {$y_{t}$};
    \node[] (x2) at (2.5,3) {$y_{t}$};
    
    % Start connecting all.
    %Intersections and displacements are used. 
    % Drawing arrows
    %\draw[->, ArrowC1] (c) -- (ct);
    \draw [->, ArrowC1] (c) -- (mux1) -- (add1) -- (c2);
    
    % Inputs
    \draw [ArrowC2] (h) -| (ibox4);
    \draw [ArrowC1] (h -| ibox1)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox1); 
    \draw [ArrowC1] (h -| ibox2)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox2);
    \draw [ArrowC1] (h -| ibox3)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox3);
    \draw [ArrowC1] (x) -- (x |- h)-| (ibox3);
    
    % Internal
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox1) -- (mux1);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox2) |- (mux2);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox3) -- (mux2);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox4) |- (mux3);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (mux2) -- (add1);
    \draw [->, ArrowC1] (add1 -| func1)++(-0.5,0) -| (func1);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (func1) -- (mux3);
    
    %Outputs
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (mux3) |- (h2);
    \draw (c2 -| x2) ++(0,-0.1) coordinate (i1);
    \draw [-, ArrowC2] (h2 -| x2)++(-0.5,0) -| (i1);
    \draw [->, ArrowC2] (i1)++(0,0.2) -- (x2);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \\
    \label{lstm_cell}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

That generates this output:

Any ideas in how can i replicate it like the figure found here? Instead of using A in left and right cells, we should write $t-1$ and $t+1$.

EDIT: Using @hpekristiansen answer, i made this:
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \fbox{
    \resizebox{0.95\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\large,
        >=LaTeX,
        cell/.style={% For the main box
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners=5mm, 
        draw,
        very thick,
        },
        operator/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        inner sep=-0.5pt,
        minimum width =.3cm,
        minimum height =.3cm,
        },
        function/.style={
        ellipse,
        draw,
        inner sep=1pt
        },
        ct/.style={
        circle,
        draw,
        line width = .75pt,
        minimum width=1cm,
        inner sep=1pt,
        },
        gt1/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        fill=green, 
        minimum width=4mm,
        minimum height=3mm,
        inner sep=1pt
        },
        gt2/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        fill=red, 
        minimum width=4mm,
        minimum height=3mm,
        inner sep=1pt
        },
        gt3/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        fill=yellow, 
        minimum width=4mm,
        minimum height=3mm,
        inner sep=1pt
        },
        ArrowC1/.style={% Arrows with rounded corners
        rounded corners=.25cm,
        thick,
        },
        ArrowC2/.style={% Arrows with big rounded corners
        rounded corners=.5cm,
        thick,
        },
        cella/.pic={
            \node [cell, minimum height =4cm, minimum width=6cm] at (0,0){};
            \node [gt1] (ibox1a) at (-2,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
            \node [gt2] (ibox2a) at (-1.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
            \node [gt2, minimum width=1cm] (ibox3a) at (-0.5,-0.75) {Tanh};
            \node [gt3] (ibox4a) at (0.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
            \node [operator] (mux1a) at (-2,1.5) {$\times$};
            \node [operator] (adda) at (-0.5,1.5) {+};
            \node [operator] (mux2a) at (-0.5,0) {$\times$};
            \node [gt3] (mux3a) at (1.5,0) {$\times$};
            \node [gt3] (funca) at (1.5,0.75) {Tanh};
            \node[] (ca) at (-4,1.5) {$C_{t-2}$};
            \node[] (ha) at (-4,-1.5) {$y_{t-2}$};
            \node[] (xa) at (-2.5,-3) {$x_{t-1}$};
            \node[] (c2a) at (4,1.5) {};
            \node[] () at (3.5, 2) {$C_{t-1}$};
            \node[] (h2a) at (4,-1.5) {};
            \node[] (x2a) at (2.5,3) {$y_{t-1}$};
            \node[] () at (3.5, -2) {$y_{t-1}$};
            % \draw [->, ArrowC1] (c) -- (mux1) -- (add1) -- (c2);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (ca) -- (mux1a);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (mux1a) -- (adda);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (adda) -- (c2a);
            \draw [ArrowC2] (ha) -| (ibox4a);
            \draw [ArrowC1] (ha -| ibox1a)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox1a); 
            \draw [ArrowC1] (ha -| ibox2a)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox2a);
            \draw [ArrowC1] (ha -| ibox3a)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox3a);
            \draw [ArrowC1] (xa) -- (xa |- ha)-| (ibox3a);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox1a) -- (mux1a);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox2a) |- (mux2a);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox3a) -- (mux2a);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox4a) |- (mux3a);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (mux2a) -- (adda);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (adda -| funca)++(-0.5,0) -| (funca);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (funca) -- (mux3a);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (mux3a) |- (h2a);
            \draw (c2a -| x2a) ++(0,-0.1) coordinate (i1a);
            \draw [-, ArrowC2] (h2a -| x2a)++(-0.5,0) -| (i1a);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (i1a)++(0,0.2) -- (x2a);
        },
        cellb/.pic={
            \node [cell, minimum height =4cm, minimum width=6cm] at (0,0){};
            \node [gt1] (ibox1b) at (-2,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
            \node [gt2] (ibox2b) at (-1.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
            \node [gt2, minimum width=1cm] (ibox3b) at (-0.5,-0.75) {Tanh};
            \node [gt3] (ibox4b) at (0.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
            \node [operator] (mux1b) at (-2,1.5) {$\times$};
            \node [operator] (add1b) at (-0.5,1.5) {+};
            \node [operator] (mux2b) at (-0.5,0) {$\times$};
            \node [gt3] (mux3b) at (1.5,0) {$\times$};
            \node [gt3] (func1b) at (1.5,0.75) {Tanh};
            \node[] (cb) at (-4,1.5) {};
            \node[] (hb) at (-4,-1.5) {};
            \node[] (xb) at (-2.5,-3) {$x_{t}$};
            \node[] (c2b) at (4,1.5) {};
            \node[] () at (3.5,2) {$C_{t}$};
            \node[] (h2b) at (4,-1.5) {};
            \node[] (x2b) at (2.5,3) {$y_{t}$};
            \node[] () at (3.5, -2) {$y_{t}$};
            % \draw [->, ArrowC1] (c) -- (mux1) -- (add1) -- (c2);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (cb) -- (mux1b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (mux1b) -- (add1b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (add1b) -- (c2b);
            \draw [ArrowC2] (hb) -| (ibox4b);
            \draw [ArrowC1] (hb -| ibox1b)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox1b); 
            \draw [ArrowC1] (hb -| ibox2b)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox2b);
            % \draw [ArrowC1] (h -| ibox3)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox3);
            \draw [ArrowC1] (xb) -- (xb |- hb)-| (ibox3b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox1b) -- (mux1b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox2b) |- (mux2b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox3b) -- (mux2b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox4b) |- (mux3b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (mux2b) -- (add1b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (add1b -| func1b)++(-0.5,0) -| (func1b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (func1b) -- (mux3b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (mux3b) |- (h2b);
            \draw (c2b -| x2b) ++(0,-0.1) coordinate (i1b);
            \draw [-, ArrowC2] (h2b -| x2b)++(-0.5,0) -| (i1b);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (i1b)++(0,0.2) -- (x2b);
        },
        cellc/.pic={
            \node [cell, minimum height =4cm, minimum width=6cm] at (0,0){};
            \node [gt1] (ibox1c) at (-2,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
            \node [gt2] (ibox2c) at (-1.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
            \node [gt2, minimum width=1cm] (ibox3c) at (-0.5,-0.75) {Tanh};
            \node [gt3] (ibox4c) at (0.5,-0.75) {$\sigma$};
            \node [operator] (mux1c) at (-2,1.5) {$\times$};
            \node [operator] (add1c) at (-0.5,1.5) {+};
            \node [operator] (mux2c) at (-0.5,0) {$\times$};
            \node [gt3] (mux3c) at (1.5,0) {$\times$};
            \node [gt3] (func1c) at (1.5,0.75) {Tanh};
            \node[] (cc) at (-4,1.5) {};
            \node[] (hc) at (-4,-1.5) {};
            \node[] (xc) at (-2.5,-3) {$x_{t+1}$};
            \node[] (c2c) at (4,1.5) {};
            \node[] () at (3.5,2) {$C_{t+1}$};
            \node[] (h2c) at (4,-1.5) {};
            \node[] (x2c) at (2.5,3) {$y_{t+1}$};
            \node[] () at (3.5, -2) {$y_{t+1}$};
            % \draw [->, ArrowC1] (c) -- (mux1) -- (add1) -- (c2);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (cc) -- (mux1c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (mux1c) -- (add1c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (add1c) -- (c2c);
            \draw [ArrowC2] (hc) -| (ibox4c);
            \draw [ArrowC1] (hc -| ibox1c)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox1c); 
            \draw [ArrowC1] (hc -| ibox2c)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox2c);
            \draw [ArrowC1] (hc -| ibox3c)++(-0.5,0) -| (ibox3c);
            \draw [ArrowC1] (xc) -- (xc |- hc)-| (ibox3c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox1c) -- (mux1c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox2c) |- (mux2c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox3c) -- (mux2c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (ibox4c) |- (mux3c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (mux2c) -- (add1c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC1] (add1c -| func1c)++(-0.5,0) -| (func1c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (func1c) -- (mux3c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (mux3c) |- (h2c);
            \draw (c2c -| x2c) ++(0,-0.1) coordinate (i1c);
            \draw [-, ArrowC2] (h2c -| x2c)++(-0.5,0) -| (i1c);
            \draw [->, ArrowC2] (i1c)++(0,0.2) -- (x2c);
        }, 
        very thick,
    ]
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-7cm]
    \pic {cella};
    \draw[rounded corners=0.5cm, fill=green!40, opacity=0.8] (-3,-2) rectangle +(6,4);
    \node[scale=3] {$t-1$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
    \draw[rounded corners=0.5cm, fill=green!40, opacity=0.8] (-3,-2) rectangle +(6,4);
    \pic {cellb};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
    \pic {cellc};
    \draw[rounded corners=0.5cm, fill=green!40, opacity=0.8] (-3,-2) rectangle +(6,4);
    \node[scale=3] {$t+1$};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    }
\end{figure}


You can use layers https://tikz.dev/gd-layered . // Instead of A you write $formula$ inside the nodes braces.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
cell/.pic={
\node[circle, draw, inner sep=-0.5pt] (A) at (-2,1.5) {$\times$};
\node[draw, fill=red] at (-0.5,-0.75) (B) {Tanh};
\draw[->] (A) |- (B);
%All things to be repeated are placed here
},
very thick,
]
\begin{scope}[xshift=-7cm]
\pic {cell};
\draw[rounded corners=0.5cm, fill=green!40, opacity=0.8] (-3,-2) rectangle +(6,4);
\node[font=\Huge, scale=3] {A};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm]
\draw[rounded corners=0.5cm, fill=green!40, opacity=0.8] (-3,-2) rectangle +(6,4);
\pic {cell};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\pic {cell};
\draw[rounded corners=0.5cm, fill=green!40, opacity=0.8] (-3,-2) rectangle +(6,4);
\node[font=\Huge, scale=3] {A};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


